# unit tests for boost::optional

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

Where can I find the unit tests for  boost::optional?

I am trying to strip out boost::optional to own code since including all of boost slows down my compilation time massively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to

> $(boost_root)\libs\optional\test?

E.g on my windows installation this would be

> C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47\libs\optional\test

On a different note, have you looked at other techniques to speed up compilation times such as precompiled headers, only including the required headers, the pimpl idiom, etc.

These can make a big difference: e.g. 
Say your class contains an instance of boost::asio::io_service, then only

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
```

in your header instead of

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

and then include other files such as the place holders, etc in your source.
This made a pretty big difference to me. Your mileage may vary...